# How to place a Rectangle in a new image with different size, while preserving the size and quality of the orignial Rectangle?

Tags: c#

I have an image that contains some letters. Each of the letters has been placed in a Rectangle object.
The rectangles are of different sizes, but i want to save each of them to a new image which has the same size. In this case 260x260.

Here is my approach:

```
foreach(Rectangle letter in letters) 
{
      Bitmap letterBitmap = img2.Clone(letter, img2.PixelFormat);
      Image newImage = (Image) letterBitmap;
      Bitmap newLetterBitmap = new Bitmap(newImage, new Size(260, 260));
}
```

The Problem is that the size of the rectangle gets changed, so it fits the new size of the Bitmap. I just want the new image to have a black background and be bigger than the original rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Bitmap newLetterBitmap = new Bitmap(260, 260);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newLetterBitmap);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(newImage, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I added g.Clear(Color.Black); to make the background black.